# Cleaning up Windows XP serial ports

Tags: usb, serial-port, serial

I have been using USB-to-serial port converters and have not been careful to plug them into -exactly- the same USB port every time. What is the best (and safest) method to clean up the giant mess of COM ports generated by Windows XP when you do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a giant mess of COM ports in the [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager), then right click -> uninstall.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't clean up something in the registry.  When I plug back in, I don't get a reasonable port number again. I discovered the hard way that Python really doesn't like port numbers greater than COM9.

Comment: Device Manager > right click on any of the 'virtual' COM ports > Properties > Port Settings > Advanced ... change the COM Port Number to your likings/requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of suggestions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/27446/how-to-remove-all-previous-devices-in-xp).

- [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html)
- [DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272/)